# PHP - downloaded image is broken

Tags: php, apache, encoding, download, image-uploading

Uploading images on the servers ends up correctly and files in my upload folders are the same that the ones that were sent.
They also display correctly on my page but after the download I can't use them.

Windows image viewer tells me "The file can't be open because it is broken or corrupted or too big"

The code :

```
$file= \FileQuery::create()->findPk($params["fileId"]);
if ($file) {
  $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $filePath = $file->getFilepath();
  header('Content-Type: '.finfo_file($finfo, $filePath));
  finfo_close($finfo);                
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .basename($filePath));
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header('Pragma: public');  

  flush();
  readfile($filePath);
}
```

When I edit the images with Notepad++ I can see that the whole file differs after download ; it starts with "‰PNG" but the final file starts with "X89PNG" just like if it got encoded a weird way...

Any clue?

Edit : I had found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621565/file-corrupt-when-click-download-link) before which looks similar but the answer does not work for me. My files have the same size before upload and after download, just the content that's encoded differently...

Also, the problem only occurs with image files. 
Pdf, zip, docx or text files are ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file corrupt when click download link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621565/file-corrupt-when-click-download-link)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 

 header('Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Pragma: no-cache');
 header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));
 exit($data);
 $data = file_get_contents('your image url')

?>
```

Comment: If you provide an answer, please explain your code and explain the reason why it differs, so you can point to the error and we altogether got the chance to learn something.